# RabbitMQ Spring "Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key" when using Java lambda parallelStream

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have a Spring Java application using RabbitMQ, and here is the scenario:

- There is a consumer receiving messages from a queue and sending them to another one. We are using "SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory" as the container factory, but when sending the messages to the other queue inside a "parallelStream" we've got an IllegalStateException **"Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key"** Exception
- When we remove the "parallelStream" it works flawlessly.

```
    public void sendMessage(final StagingMessage stagingMessage, final Long timestamp, final String country) {

        final List<TransformedMessage> messages = processMessageList(stagingMessage);

        messages.parallelStream().forEach(message -> {
            final TransformedMessage transformedMessage = buildMessage(timestamp, ApiConstants.POST_METHOD, country);
            myMessageSender.sendQueue(country, transformedMessage);
        });
    }
```

Connectio Facotory, where the lookup key is set:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitBaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private QueueProperties queueProperties;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryA, final ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryB) {

        final SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory simpleRoutingConnectionFactory = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
        final Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (final String queue : queueProperties.getAQueueMap().values()) {
            map.put("[" + queue + "]", connectionFactoryA);
        }

        for (final String queue : queueProperties.getBQueueMap().values()) {
            map.put("[" + queue + "]", connectionFactoryB);
        }

        simpleRoutingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactories(map);
        return simpleRoutingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter() {

        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow!

You should always show the pertinent code and configuration beans when asking questions like this.

I assume you are using the `RoutingConnectionFactory`.

It uses a `ThreadLocal` to store the lookup key so the send has to happen on the same thread that set the key.

You generally should never go asynchronous in a listener anyway; you risk message loss. To increase concurrency, use the concurrency properties on the container.

**EDIT**

One technique would be to convey the lookup key in a message header:

```
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate template(ConnectionFactory rcf) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(rcf);
        Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("messageProperties.headers['cfSelector']");
        rabbitTemplate.setSendConnectionFactorySelectorExpression(expression);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .parallel()
            .mapToObj(i -> in + i)
            .forEach(val -> {
                this.template.convertAndSend("bar", val.toUpperCase(), msg -> {
                    msg.getMessageProperties().setHeader("cfSelector", "[bar]");
                    return msg;
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that Gary. You are right, we are using RoutingConnectionFactory. So we should send it in a serial format to the other queue, right? About concurrency, we've tried setting "concurrentConsumers" and "maxConcurrentConsumers" with values as big as 1000 and did not work.

Comment: Even when setting these concurrency parameters with higher values, we got the same exception "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]"

Comment: I mean instead of using `parallel` to increase the throughput, increase the container concurrency instead. You need to set the lookup key on the same thread that actually does the send. Going async within a listener is rarely a good idea. If you can edit the question to show your listener code, it would help me understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey Gary, I've updated with a sample of the code. This method is called by the listener

Comment: I need to see where you are setting up the lookup key - if you do it within `sendQueue()` you should be ok because it will then be setup on the right thread.

Comment: We are not doing within the sendQueue. It's been created before. New code added to the description

Comment: Can you show your `RabbitTemplate`? Are you using transactions?

Comment: I edit the answer with one technique that should work.

Comment: Thanks Gary, will try that.